# média da população por cidade de cada estado

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Boa tarde, aqui estou empacado em mais questão de um trabalho, precisa fazer uma consulta onde ela retorne a média da população por cidade de cada estado, consegui até executar algumas pesquisas mas todas deram números absurdamente grandes que vou mostrar a abaixo.

`SELECT e.nome,  AVG(m.populacao) pop
    FROM municipio m
    INNER JOIN estado e
    ON e.codestado = m.codestado 
    GROUP BY e.nome
    ORDER BY pop ASC`

Comment: Municipio já tem a população agregada ?

Comment: Neste casos faça aberta para um estado e confira.

Comment: Desculpe, mas vc não deveria pedir para que outras pessoas façam o seu trabalho por vc. Tente se esforçar para fazê-lo. Se é uma questão, foram passadas as instruções para permitir que vc o faça.

Comment: @Motta , a tabela de municipio se relaciona com a de estado por meio do CODESTADO, e a tabela regiao se relaciona com estado por meio de CODREGIAO. Eu imagino que tenha que fazer a soma da população dos estados e depois fazer a media, já tentei várias maneiras mas nenhuma delas pareceu dar o resultado certo. Se puder dizer qual comando devo usar pra fazer, comecei a estudar BD agora, então meu conhecimento é só o básico

Comment: Não estou pedindo pra fazer por mim BTW, tinha umas 18  questões nesse trabalho, respondi todas as outras sozinho, como o colega está dizendo que estou pedindo pra fazer por mim.

Comment: Sua sql me parece correta , tentou fazer um caso de um estado ? Pegue um pequeno , Sergipe ou Acre e faça um analitico para testar.

Comment: SELECT e.nome, m.nome , m.populacao pop
    FROM municipio m
    INNER JOIN estado e
    ON e.codestado = m.codestado andve.codestado = 'AC'

Comment: @Motta tava vendo aqui que o resultado pode estar certo mas tem muitas casas decimais, e eu  não tinha visto isso, por isso estava achando que estava errado,mas observando agora pode estar certo, por exemplo o do amazonas está dando '51966.774193548387'

Comment: @Motta realmente acho que estava certo, usei ROUND para arredondar para duas casas decimais e aparentemente estava certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua *query* está correta, sua metodologia de teste é que está errada:

> consegui até executar algumas pesquisas mas todas deram números
>   absurdamente grandes

O que é grande? O que é pequeno? Qual era o valor esperado de retorno?
O fato é que sem uma referência não há como determinar se a sua consulta está certa ou errada.

Como você não especificou a estrutura das tabelas `estado` e `municipio`, vou me basear na sua *query* e assumir que sua estrutura de tabelas seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE estado
(
  codestado INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  uf CHARACTER VARYING(2),
  nome TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE municipio
(
  codmunicipio INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  codestado INTEGER REFERENCES estado (codestado), 
  nome TEXT,
  populacao INTEGER
);
```

Agora, vamos inserir alguns dados nas tabelas criadas:

```
INSERT INTO estado (codestado, uf, nome) VALUES
( 1, 'PI', 'Piauí' ),
( 2, 'MA', 'Maranhão' ),
( 3, 'CE', 'Ceará' );

INSERT INTO municipio ( codmunicipio, codestado, nome, populacao ) VALUES
( 1, 1, 'Teresina', 864845 ),
( 2, 1, 'Parnaíba', 153078 ),
( 3, 1, 'Picos', 78222 ),
( 4, 2, 'São Luís', 1101884 ),
( 5, 2, 'Imperatriz', 258682 ),
( 6, 2, 'São José de Ribamar', 177687 ),
( 7, 3, 'Fortaleza', 2669342 ),
( 8, 3, 'Caucaia', 362400 ),
( 9, 3, 'Juazeiro do Norte', 274207 );
```

Primeiramente, vamos fazer uma simples consulta na tabela de `municipios` para se determinar qual o valor da **média da população por cidade de um determinado estado da federação** que devemos esperar em nossos testes, dividir para conquistar, vamos lá:

```
--- Média populacional apenas das cidades do estado do Piauí
SELECT AVG(populacao) FROM municipio WHERE codestado = 1;
```

Saída:

```
|               avg |
|-------------------|
| 365381.6666666667 |
```

Não sei se esse valor é grande ou pequeno, mas ele é uma boa referência para verificar se *queries* mais complexas estão funcionando como o esperado.

Agora vamos ao monstro:

```
SELECT
  e.codestado,
  e.nome,
  AVG(m.populacao) pop
FROM
   estado e 
INNER JOIN
  municipio m ON (e.codestado = m.codestado)
GROUP BY
  e.codestado
ORDER BY
  pop ASC;
```

Saída:

```
| codestado | uf |     nome |               pop |
|-----------|----|----------|-------------------|
|         1 | PI |    Piauí | 365381.6666666667 |
|         2 | MA | Maranhão |            512751 |
|         3 | CE |    Ceará |           1101983 |
```

Repare que valor da média populacional esperado para o estado do Piauí corresponde ao valor esperado, demonstrando que seu `INNER JOIN` e seu `GROUP BY` estão funcionando corretamente.

Veja tudo isso rodando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ffe6b/7)

Comment: Eu só faria o analitico listando as cidades do estado e calculando a média.